# ORA-01408: such column list already indexed

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Oracle SQL-Developer generates DDL statements of already exising database tables (items). It's quite strange that the generated DDL statements can't be applied within a new database instance. Here's a simplified example of the DDL

```
CREATE TABLE AB
  (
    "A"      NUMBER(*,0),
    "B"   NUMBER(*,0),
    "C" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
    CONSTRAINT "CHK_AB_A_NN" CHECK (A       IS NOT NULL) ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "CHK_AB_B_NN" CHECK (B       IS NOT NULL) ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_AB" PRIMARY KEY ("A", "B")
  );
CREATE INDEX "IDX_AB_A" ON "AB"("A");
CREATE INDEX "IDX_AB_B" ON "AB"("B");
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_AB" ON "AB"("A", "B");
```

If I execute those statements within a new oracle instance, I get the error:

*`SQL-Fehler: ORA-01408: Diese Spaltenliste hat bereits einen Index
 1. 00000 -  "such column list already indexed"`*

What's the reason for this error?

Comment: Which version of SQL Developer, and database? Version 4 doesn't seem to do this, even if the index is created first and the PK is added later with an `alter table`. Not sure if it's an issue in the client or in the database version, but I'd suspect the client just not being quite clever enough.

Comment: @AlexPoole QL-Developer: Version 2.1.1.64 **AND** Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: I'd strongly suspect it's the old version of SQL Developer not being clever enough to realise the index is included in the PK then. If you can I'd suggest you try a newer version and see if it behaves properly (4 seems to but is [still in beta](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-releasenotes-v4-1925251.html)). You could also raise it on [their forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=260) but not sure how much interest there would still be in version 2...

Comment: I had the same problem. After deleting the UNIQUE constraint i could add the index and then add the unique constraint again.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The part:

```
CONSTRAINT "PK_AB" PRIMARY KEY ("A", "B")
```

is generating an index. Primary key constraint cannot exists without an index. However, the part:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_AB" ON "AB"("A", "B");
```

is generating yet another index with the same columns. This is the reason for the error. Quite strange though, that the Oracle tool is generating a wrong script :) Maybe it's a bug.

Answer (score 6):

Your primary key constraint in the CREATE TABLE statement automatically creates unique index  on ("A","B"), since it's PRIMARY KEY. Error is then raised, since you try to re-create already existing UNIQUE INDEX on same columns.

UPDATE: I've tested it with Oracle SQL Developer 3.2.20.09 and the above mentioned problem is not present. Are you possibly using older version ?

Comment: Yes, it's the version 2.1.1.64. Anoter reason to upgrade :) THX!